# Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC module is unable to find jQuery in Webpack bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webpack, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I posted an issue for Webpack and was asked to post the question here.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5594

It's important to note that the "all JavaScript" version of the grid works fine, and has no issue finding jQuery. It's only the Razor version that's hosed.

I get an error to the console that states that "jQuery is not defined" when using the Razor syntax for [Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

A support ticket was initially put in with Telerik, who subsequently asked that a ticket be submitted with Webpack stating that:

> ...the main issue is that jQuery has to be available in the bundle and loaded before the Kendo UI scripts and it is not.

I'm at a loss as to whether I should expect this to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Or is it that this part of KendoUI can only be used with more traditional methods of loading dependencies?

Comment: I have this issue as well. Have you solved this issue?

Comment: If you’re using the MVC package, then you’re basically out of luck. The Telerik folks were never able to give me a good answer. However, you might be okay if you just include jQuery the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Those imports are happening before your window assignments are happening. require() calls aren't hoisted to the top of the window, so try this instead:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
window.jquery = $;

require('@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.web');
require('@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc');
```